# Displaying an ImageStream inside an image tag in an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, filestream

I am getting an imageStream from the db, which is a `Byte[]`, and I wish to display this inside an html image tag.

Currently I have the following:-

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%=ImageStream %>" alt="<%=ImageName %>" />
```

I am trying to get the ImageStream as follows from the code-behind :-

```
ImageStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(CurrentUser.Avatar);
```

`CurrentUser.Avatar` is a `Byte[]`.

How can I display this byte into an image tag?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your image src clearly states, `image/png;base64`; your stream has to be Base64 encoded.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%=Convert.ToBase64String(CurrentUser.Avatar)%>"
     alt="<%=ImageName %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode it to base64 - use [`System.Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).

```
ImageStream = System.Convert.ToBase64String(CurrentUser.Avatar);
```